# Default Param on Polymer.js Input Range

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to use Polymer.js with an `input[type="range"]` to bind the current value of the range slider in an associated `<output>` element. Everything works with the exception of my default input value in the `input`. The value param doesn't show up in the DOM, and my range sliders are set to zero, as seen here:

**Initial Load**

[image]

**After Slide Event**

After I update/slide the sliders on the input, the expected value is bound to the `<output>` as seen below.

[image]

Template

```
<dom-module id="item-selection">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="item-selection.scss" />
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sliders}}">
      <div class="slider-group">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <output>{{item.initialValue}}</output>
        <input type="range"
          min="{{item.minValue}}"
          max="{{item.maxValue}}"
          value="{{item.initialValue::input}}"
          id="{{item.id}}"
          step="1"
        >
      </div>
    </template>
    <a href="#" class="button">Button Text</a>
  </template>

  <script src="item-selection.js"></script>
</dom-module>
```

JS:

```
Polymer({
  is: "item-selection",
  ready: function() {
    this.sliders = [
      {
        name: "item-one",
        id: "item-one-id",
        initialValue: 175,
        minValue: 100,
        maxValue: 200
      },
      {
        name: "item-two",
        id: "item-one-id",
        initialValue: 175,
        minValue: 100,
        maxValue: 281
      },
      {
        name: "item-three",
        id: "item-one-id",
        initialValue: 150,
        minValue: 100,
        maxValue: 200
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

DOM Inspection

```
<div class="slider-group style-scope item-selection">
  <label class="style-scope item-selection">item-two</label>
  <output class="style-scope item-selection">175</outpute>
  <input type="range" step="1" 
    class="style-scope item-selection" 
    id="item-one-id" 
    max="281" min="100">
</div>
...
```

Is there a way to set a default value as well as allow the databinding on the input elements? I looked through https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding to see if I could find a solution, but nothing seems obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** As you discovered, the order of the `max` and `value` bindings changes whether the `<input>`'s value is initialized (and that varies by browser). I've created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3697) for this Polymer bug.

You might consider using a [`<paper-slider>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-slider) instead, which doesn't exhibit this problem in any browser:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-slider/paper-slider.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sliders}}">
      <div class="slider-group">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <output>{{item.initialValue}}</output>
        <paper-slider
               min="{{item.minValue}}"
               max="{{item.maxValue}}"
               value="{{item.initialValue}}"
               step="1"></paper-slider>
      </div>
    </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties : {
            sliders: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [
                  {
                    name: "item-one",
                    id: "item-one-id",
                    initialValue: 120,
                    minValue: 100,
                    maxValue: 200
                  },
                  {
                    name: "item-two",
                    id: "item-one-id",
                    initialValue: 175,
                    minValue: 100,
                    maxValue: 200
                  },
                  {
                    name: "item-three",
                    id: "item-one-id",
                    initialValue: 150,
                    minValue: 100,
                    maxValue: 200
                  }
                ];
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vKNVyr?editors=1000)</sup>

---

Binding `max` seems to cause the problem for some reason. Removing the `max` binding and hard-coding it allows the initial value to take effect, as seen in the demo below.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sliders}}">
      <div class="slider-group">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <output>{{item.initialValue}}</output>
        <input type="range"
               min="{{item.minValue}}"
               max="200"
               value="{{item.initialValue::input}}"
               step="1">
      </div>
    </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties : {
            sliders: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [
                  {
                    name: "item-one",
                    id: "item-one-id",
                    initialValue: 120,
                    minValue: 100,
                    maxValue: 200
                  },
                  {
                    name: "item-two",
                    id: "item-one-id",
                    initialValue: 175,
                    minValue: 100,
                    maxValue: 200
                  },
                  {
                    name: "item-three",
                    id: "item-one-id",
                    initialValue: 150,
                    minValue: 100,
                    maxValue: 200
                  }
                ];
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RRWJzm?editors=1000)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help... interestingly, based on your suggestion, I tried moving the `max` after the `value` and now it works.

Comment: Interesting. I was in the process of filing a Polymer bug. I'll add that to my report. I'll also update the answer to be useful.

Comment: Hmm. It's worth noting that trick causes the original bad behavior in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

@tony19 - thanks for your feedback. Turns out that simply placing the `max` after the `value` does the trick.

```
<input type="range"
  min="{{item.minValue}}"
  value="{{item.initialValue::input}}"
  max="{{item.maxValue}}"
  id="{{item.id}}"
  step="1"
>
```

Comment: Hmm. It's worth noting that trick causes the original bad behavior in Firefox.

Comment: Ughhh... I didn't do any browser testing. Thanks for the update.